# can we use memcpy in thread

Tags: android-ndk, memcpy

can we use memcpy to copy data from a thread to class member ?

```
struct x
{
x_state *pState;
x_unit m_input;
x_unit m_out;
};

struct x_buffer
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
int t;
char* buf;
} ;
class xyz{
public:
    static THREAD_FUNC void ThreadFunc(void* arg);
    static CALL_BACK void handle_thread_data(struct Session* session, event *e);
public
    x_buffer *m_buffer;
y_struct *m_strt1, *m_strt2;
}
```

m_buffer , m-str1,m_str2 are created on heap in class constructor by calling malloc.
handle_thread_data is the callback called , when i start thread. 
I am trying to copy my data from session object to m_buffer using memcpy.
 But i am getting crash.Below is the back trace.

```
  #00  pc 0000e2f0  /system/lib/libc.so
  I/DEBUG   (  100):     #01  pc 00039cad  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+26)
```

Code is working fine if the m_buffer is global buffer.

Comment: What's the fault address reported for the crash?  Can you show the actual `malloc` call?

Comment: m_buffer = (X_buffer*)malloc(sizeof(X_buffer)); -- this is how i alloc and also for buf* in x_buffer, i am allocating separately.